# Copy and pasting rows of a table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table, lets say table1 which is AF6:AH100. I want to write a macro that, for each row in this table, it pastes the three cells into W4, X4, Y4, then when the formulas update, it pastes AC3 and AD3 into AI6 and AJ6.

So it would go like this:

FOR N IN 6:100
COPY(AFN,AGN,AHN)
PASTE -> W4, X4, Y4
*formulas update*
COPY(AC3, AD3)
PASTE -> AIN, AJN

Here is what I have:

```
Sub RefreshFactors()

Dim rng As Range
cell As Range

Set rng = Range("AF6:AH101")

For Each Row In rng.Rows

{not sure how to copy paste multiple cells at a time}
    
End Sub
```

Can someone help me write this please?

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service, update your question with your code attempt and explain which part is not working (Error? Tell us the error message and which line. Not working as expected? Tell us what's the expected output).

Comment: Hi Raymond, the pseudo code provided writes to (AIN, AJN) dependent on the paramater N.

Comment: Yes I just saw that, let me give it a try @Prince

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I am still googling myself but I have been trying for a while.

Comment: Give the answer below a try although I'm not sure why couldn't you just put the Formula into column `AI:AJ` and reference directly to column `AF:AH`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshFactors()
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to the correct sheet name
            
    Const startRow As Long = 6  'First row to process
    Const endRow As Long = 101 'Last row to process
            
    Const srcRng As String = "AF?:AH?" 'Source range, ? is the token for the row number during loop
    Const finalRng As String = "AI?:AJ?" 'Output range, ? is the token for the row number during loop
    
    Dim valueRng As Range
    Set valueRng = ws.Range("W4:Y4")
    
    Dim formulaRng As Range
    Set formulaRng = ws.Range("AC3:AD3")
            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            
    Dim i As Long
    For i = startRow To endRow
        valueRng.Value2 = ws.Range(Replace(srcRng, "?", i)).Value2
        'Application.Calculate 'should be unnecessary but uncomment this if the formula is not updating itself after above line for some reason
        ws.Range(Replace(finalRng, "?", i)).Value2 = formulaRng.Value2
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Simply from running it - yes it works as expected, so answer accepted. Thank you Raymond. I will now work through it to understand it for my learning and let you know if I have a question.

Comment: @Prince Please consider my latest comment above, on the surface the end result doesn't seems like something that requires VBA to achieve.

Comment: The values of W4 and Y4 are a function of what is in AF,AG,AH. Whenever AF,AG,AH are updated it changes many values in my worksheet, that in turn update W4, Y4.